# SQL Query -AVG Last two days

Tags: sql, mysql

I m trying to get Average of last two records and group them by name.

```
OId     ODate        Value      Name
1      05/01/2011   25          Mike
2      05/01/2011   56      Peter
3      05/01/2011   09      Robert
4      06/01/2011   21          Mike
5      06/01/2011   52      Peter
6      06/01/2011   04      Robert
7      10/01/2011   28          Mike
8      10/01/2011   57      Peter
9      10/01/2011   03      Robert

SELECT Name, avg(Value) as avg_score
FROM (
  SELECT Name, Value FROM S_ORDER BY dessc ODate 60
)
GROUP BY Name;
```

Thank you.!

Comment: Thank you! The last 2 dates per name? - Yes
 
What RDBMS are you using? - Mysql

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tLast.Name, 
  (tLast.Value + COALESCE(tLast2.Value, 0)) / CASE WHEN tLast2.Value IS NULL 1 ELSE 2 END As avg_score
FROM (
    SELECT last1.Name, MAX(last1.MaxID) MaxID, MAX(last2.OId) MaxID2
    FROM (
        SELECT Name, MAX(OId) MaxID
        FROM tableName
        GROUP BY Name
      ) last1 LEFT JOIN tableName last2 ON Name = last1.Name AND OId < last1.MaxID
    GROUP BY last1.Name
  ) rs JOIN tableName tLast ON rs.MaxID = tLast.OId
  LEFT JOIN tableName tLast2 ON rs.MaxID2 = tLast2.OId
ORDER BY tLast.Name
```

Grouping by name is not recommended, you should store a `user_id` which points to a `user` table, instead of storing the name.

Comment: Hi, The Scrum Meister, Thanks for the input.!

Comment: +1. Basically seems the most optimal approach, only I would probably not rely on IDs. Data could be antedated, so I think it would be better to calculate `MAX(ODate)`. And good point about grouping by names. They might be used only illustratively, though.

Comment: @andriy-m I was assuming the `OId` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, which will be better then `MAX(ODate)` since there cannot be ties.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a standard ANSI SQL solution:

```
SELECT Name, avg(Value) as avg_score
FROM (
  SELECT Name, 
         Value, 
         row_number() over (partition by name order by Odate desc) as row_num
  FROM your_table
) t
GROUP BY Name
WHERE row_num <= 2;
```

Comment: I am trying on MySQL; seems partition function is for Oracle. wondering is there any workaround for MySQL.

Comment: @web21: it's actually not Oracle specific (it also works on DB2, SQL Server, PostgreSQL and Teradata). But I don't have an idea for a workaround in MySQL apart from Scrum Meister's solution.